# How do I modify this page peel effect without messing it up?

Tags: css

I am trying to adapt the page peel effect shown [here](http://cssdeck.com/labs/page-curl-box-shadow). My fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/KSXqg/6/show)

I'm trying to make 2 modifications:

1. Increase the width to 90% (they have 800px)

   - If I do this, then this screws up the dropshadow effect, showing some whitespace where the shadows should be
2. Put the page peel on all 4 corners.

   - I've tried all sorts of combinations of the classes: "shadow-bottom shadow-top", "shadow-right shadow-left", among others.

How do I accomplish both?

```
<div class="page-curl shadow-bottom">
    <h2>Bottom shadow, both sides</h2>
    <p>Freegan fixie banh mi, pickled art party trust fund iphone blog etsy occupy cardigan fap ethnic. Sartorial sriracha vinyl lo-fi cardigan. Tofu fingerstache vegan, shoreditch marfa pour-over occupy 8-bit american apparel four loko fixie lomo vice. Freegan irony chambray jean shorts PBR selvage. PBR messenger bag VHS, umami sustainable godard portland single-origin coffee. Wolf whatever butcher messenger bag yr american apparel fap. Tattooed master cleanse cred, narwhal gluten-free sriracha organic next level put a bird on it.</p>
</div>
....full code on my jsfiddle link
```

Comment: Your fiddle is 90% and it seems to work fine (for point #1). Unless you want the shadows to be a fixed height.

Comment: if you look closer the drop shadow effect is all screwed up at 90% (compare it to the original code I linked to)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[I created a demo with the intended effects here](http://jsfiddle.net/barney/HttKU/).

**EDIT:** catered for variable width bug by fixing the percentage-based width of the original, which gave fixed values for every dimension except pseudo element width, at 40%. 40% of 800px (the container's specified width) = 320px, which is what we'll secify here to resolve the clipped shadows.

The other problem is that the original author wrote the code in such a way that shadows would only be applied to the `.page-curl` element: I separated out the CSS rules such that `.page-curl` only govern's the element's internal appearance.

The revised CSS means you can create as many elements as you want with shadow effects, without bringing in properties like padding, border, background, width, etc:

```
[class*=shadow] {
    position: relative;
}

[class*=shadow]:before, 
[class*=shadow]:after {
    background: none;
    bottom: 12px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 10px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 10px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    box-shadow: 0 10px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    content: "";
    height: 10px;
    left: 12px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 320px;
    z-index: -1;
    -moz-transform: skew(-4deg) rotate(-4deg);
    -webkit-transform: skew(-4deg) rotate(-4deg);
    transform: skew(-4deg) rotate(-4deg);
}

[class*=shadow]:after {
    -moz-transform: skew(4deg) rotate(4deg);
    -webkit-transform: skew(4deg) rotate(4deg);
    transform: skew(4deg) rotate(4deg);
    left: auto;
    right: 12px;
}
```

Basically, this code says that if an element has a class containing the text `shadow`, we can give it these `::before` and `::after` elements. Next, the rules dictating specific directions have got the `.page-curl` class chucked out.

At this point we're still limited to 2 shadows per element (we can only have one `::before` and one `::after` element): the solution, then, is to create 2 nested divs:

```
<div class="container shadow-top-bottom shadow-right">
    <div class="page-curl shadow-top-bottom shadow-left">
    </div>
</div>
```

So the 1st div takes care of the top and bottom shadows on the right, the 2ndtakes care of those on the left.

Incidentally, the 2nd has all the `.page-curl` properties, and the `.container` class on the 1st takes care of your 90% width requirement.

Comment: @Mr.Gaga updated my answer — failed to notice the variable width issue!

Comment: thx for the follow-up. this has been driving me nuts for a while.

Answer (score 0):

The peel shadow won't be as tall, but it still looks great! Make the following small changes on both of the following it will fix this for you:

[Here is the jsFiddle for it](http://jsfiddle.net/chrisallenmoore/Eegzr/) 
and [here is what it looks like on the page](http://jsfiddle.net/chrisallenmoore/Eegzr/show/)

```
.shadow-top-bottom.shadow-left:after {
display: block;
bottom: auto;
top: 20px; /* change from top: 15px; to top: 20px;*/
right: auto;
left: 12px;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 -10px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 -10px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
box-shadow: 0 -10px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);}

.shadow-top-bottom.shadow-right:before {
display: block;
bottom: auto;
top: 20px; /* change from top: 15px; to top: 20px;*/
right: 12px;
left: auto;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 -10px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 -10px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
box-shadow: 0 -10px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);}
```